# Java: Error while parsing XML document as text

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse XML document as String by using the following

```
Document parse = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlFile)));
```

but I'm getting this error

[Fatal Error] The entity "Ouml" was referenced, but not declared.

I tried escape and unescape xmlFile String using Apache StringEscapeUtils but still having errors

Comment: Its telling you theres something wrong with the xml, at an element named "Ouml".  By the sounds of your question, you should be treating the file as a regular file (java.util.Scanner?) rather than using an xml parser?

Comment: Cant really add much more without seeing the xml file.

Comment: source file of 
http://www.gazetevatan.com/rss/gundem.xml

Answer (score 2):

HTML 4.0 knows 252 predefined character-entities like `&Ouml;`, `&szlig;` etc.

XML on the other hand only has 5:

```
&quot;
&amp;
&apos;
&lt;
&gt;
```

You can't use named character-entities from html other than those without defining them first.

So when using `StringEscapeUtils` make sure you use `escapeXml()` instead of `escapeHtml4()`.